# Using Count and Case but only counting occurence once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of customers who have purchased a number of services and which have a number of billable charges next to them:

```
| CustAccount | Service  | Charge  | Value  |
|-------------|----------|---------|--------|
| M12345      | ABC123   | SE      | 102.10 |
| M12345      | ABC123   | SE      | 5.36   |
| M12345      | ABC123   | SE      | 250.36 |
| M12345      | ABC123   | OS      | 150.99 |
| M18970      | ABC123   | SE      | 56.35  |
| M18970      | ABC123   | OS      | 9.99   |
| M18970      | ABC123   | SV      | 77.77  |
| M72350      | ABC123   | OS      | 9.99   |
| M72350      | ABC123   | AB      | 9.99   |
```

What I would like to do is run a query which counts the number of unique customers and determines how many of them have had an `SE` charge. The theory being that EVERY customer should have at least one `SE` charge and I am trying to determine the integrity of the data.

So my ideal output is:

```
| Service | Customers_count | SE_charges |
|---------|-----------------|------------|
| ABC123  | 3               | 2          |
```

My query so far is:

```
SELECT Service, COUNT (DISTINCT CustAccount) AS Customers_count,
    COUNT (CASE WHEN Charge = 'SE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS SE_charges
FROM MyTable
```

However it seems to count duplicate `SE` values for each customer and I cannot work out how to only count 1 `SE` for each customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping, i understood PROBLEM correctly

i think just group by is missing.

```
SELECT Service, COUNT (DISTINCT CustAccount) AS Customers_count,
    COUNT (distinct CASE WHEN Charge = 'SE' THEN CustAccount END) AS SE_charges
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Service
```

Answer (score 3):

If you return CustAccount instead of 1 you can use distinct on it:

```
SELECT 
    Service
    , COUNT (DISTINCT CustAccount) AS Customers_count
    , COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN Charge = 'SE' THEN CustAccount ELSE NULL END) AS SE_charges
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Service
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sampe query:
(It's duplicate answer with other people)

```
 ;WITH tb(CustAccount ,Service ,Charge ,Value)AS(
    SELECT 'M12345','ABC123','SE ',102.10  UNION
    SELECT 'M12345','ABC123','SE ',5.36   UNION
    SELECT 'M12345','ABC123','SE ',250.36  UNION
    SELECT 'M12345','ABC123',' OS ',150.99  UNION
    SELECT 'M18970','ABC123','SE ',56.35   UNION
    SELECT 'M18970','ABC123','OS ', 9.99    UNION
    SELECT 'M18970','ABC123',' SV ',77.77   UNION
    SELECT 'M72350','ABC123','OS ', 9.99    UNION
    SELECT 'M72350','ABC123','AB  ',9.99   
    ) 
    SELECT Service,COUNT(DISTINCT tb.CustAccount) AS Customers_count
                  ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tb.Charge='SE' THEN tb.CustAccount ELSE NULL END )SE_charges
                  --,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tb.Charge='SE' THEN tb.CustAccount+tb.Charge ELSE NULL END )SE_charges
     FROM tb
    GROUP BY tb.Service
```

```
Service Customers_count SE_charges
------- --------------- -----------
ABC123  3               2
```